# How create JPA query with dynamicly parameters?

Tags: java, jpa, jpql

I have this method:

```
 public List<User> getReport(String name, int age, String sName, Date bd, 

     String address, String msg2, int first, int pageSize) {
     List<User> result = new ArrayList<>();
     result = em.createQuery("from User u, User.class)
                    .setFirstResult(first)
                    .setMaxResults(pageSize)
                    .getResultList();
     return result;
    }
```

Now, this method return all data. I need sett dynamicly parameters. I can make this:

```
result = em.createQuery("from User u WHERE u.age = :age", User.class)
                    .setParameter("age", age)
                    .setFirstResult(first)
                    .setMaxResults(pageSize)
                    .getResultList();
```

But if my `age` is null - I dont get result. And with another fields.

I need somethign like:

```
if(age != null){
em.createQuery("from User u WHERE u.age = :age", User.class)
                        .setParameter("age", age)
}

if(name!= null){
em.createQuery("from User u WHERE u.age = :age AND u.name= :name", User.class)
                        .setParameter("age", age)
}
```

I can format string query like:

```
String query = "from User u WHER";
```

and them concate this string

```
if(age != null){
query = query +"u.age = :age";
em.createQuery("from User u WHERE u.age = :age", User.class)
                        .setParameter("age", age)
}
```

But I thing it is bad practice.

Comment: so what exactly is your question?

Comment: How create JPA query with dynamicly parameters?

Comment: JPQL queries start "SELECT " (or UPDATE/DELETE). Omitting that because one implementation allows you to is "bad practice"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All parameters are picking up the map, as I create a dynamic query.

**You can try:**

```
public List<User> getReport(String name, Integer age, String sName, Date bd, 

 String address, String msg2, int first, int pageSize) {

    Map<String, Object> paramaterMap = new HashMap<String, Object>();
    List<String> whereClause = new ArrayList<String>();

    StringBuilder queryBuilder = new StringBuilder();
    queryBuilder.append("select u from User u ");

    if (!name.isEmpty()){
        whereClause.add(" u.name =:name ");
        paramaterMap.put("category", category);
    }
    if (age != null){
        whereClause.add(" u.age =:age ");
        paramaterMap.put("age", age);
    }
   if (!sName.isEmpty()){
        whereClause.add(" u.sName =:sName ");
        paramaterMap.put("sName", sName);
    }
    if (bd != null){
        whereClause.add(" u.bd =:bd ");
        paramaterMap.put("bd", bd);
    }
    if (!address.isEmpty()){
        whereClause.add(" u.address =:address ");
        paramaterMap.put("address", address);
    }
   if (!msg2.isEmpty()){
        whereClause.add(" u.msg2 =:msg2 ");
        paramaterMap.put("msg2", msg2);
    }

    queryBuilder.append(" where " + StringUtils.join(whereClause, " and "));
    Query jpaQuery = entityManager.createQuery(queryBuilder.toString());

    for(String key :paramaterMap.keySet()) {
            jpaQuery.setParameter(key, paramaterMap.get(key));
    }

    jpaQuery.setFirstResult(first)
    jpaQuery.setMaxResults(pageSize)

    return  jpaQuery.getResultList();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I guess that you mixed up the wording. By using something like `u.age = :age` you have a *dynamic parameter*, since you can change the value of age every time you use the query.

What you are likely looking for is *dynamic queries*. Although you can do this by just concatenating strings. This is nothing else than building your own (small) query builder.

JPA comes already with a full blown query builder called [Criteria API](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/gjivm.html#gjivs). IMHO the API isn't self explaining or easy to learn but google easily reveals you a lot of examples which get you started.